# Printer Queue for Epson SX115

Tags: 10.10, printing

I have an Epson SX115. It used to work fine until I unplugged it and moved it upstairs.

When I plug it back in even if I delete it from the Printer list and re-install it every time I go to print I get a queue and no action from the printer?!?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible you have previous documents that are still trying to print, blocking anything new from coming in.

Trying printing something new and then clicking onto the printer icon in the indicator applets at the top right. You might have several print "jobs" waiting to go. Just cancel them all out and print again.